# Unique Maximum Likelihood Estimator which is not sufficient

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I'm looking for an example for a statistical model for which Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\hat{\theta}(\vec{Y})$ for $\theta$ exists, and satisfies the following conditions:

1. It is unique. Equivalently, the maximal value of the likelihood is obtained only for one point $\theta$, for every sample vector $\vec{y}$.
   Note that this condition implies that $S(\vec{Y})$ is a function of any sufficient statistic (this is a simple result).
2. $\hat{\theta}(\vec{Y})$ itself is not sufficient.

I've been looking for examples here, but I only found examples for MLEs that aren't functions of sufficient statistics (as the first condition doesn't hold). I also tried playing with examples but it didn't quite work.   I'd appreciate your help finding one.

Comment: Why do you think such an example exists?

Comment: Can't you get silly examples like $\theta=\mu+\frac12\sigma^2$ for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom The belief that otherwise it would be a well-known statement about MLEs